# What is correct method assigning array in struct

Tags: c

I'm a total noob so this might be totally off but why

```
struct staff{
    int id;
    char lastdate[8];
    char codeid[8];
};
```

in main I'm taking data from Mysql and:

```
...
while((row = mysql_fetch_row(confres)))
{
    char *codeid = row[0];
    char *maxdate = row[1];

    info[i].id=i;
    strcpy(info[i].codeid, codeid);
    strcpy(info[i].lastdate, maxdate);

    i++;
}
...
```

lastdate is in form YYYYMMDD and codeid a string.

When printing array out why is it 'lastdate's is ok but codeid which is string is just empty?

```
ID: 0 
   SHORT:  
   LAST DATE : 20170929 

ID: 1 
   SHORT:  
   LAST DATE : 20170929 
...
```

Comment: If `codeid` is a string then `row[0]` should also contain string. So, instead of `char *codeid = row[0];` use `char *codeid = &row[0];`.

Comment: That gives me a warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  char *codeid = &row[0];

Comment: You are not reserving space for the null terminator for the last date, and you are not doing any checking of string length at all, setting yourself up for buffer overflows.

Comment: codeid[8] is defined in the struct. Codeid is 5 characters long e.g. "ABC1D" so \0 should also be covered or am I wrong?

Comment: @Ommik But `lastdate` isn't big enough. So the null terminator of `lastdate` is overwriting the first byte of `codeid`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Wasn't even looking the problem from there. Now works as I intended for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `lastdate` big enough to hold the 8 characters of the date plus the null terminator, so the structure should be:

```
struct staff{
    int id;
    char lastdate[9];
    char codeid[8];
};
```

You were writing outside the array, which results in undefined behavior.